# Same View size for All devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin app i've a `Grid` with `HeightRequest = 200` i've checked it on different screen size devices on android, Height is different on each device may be because of xamarin uses `dp`. I want it to be same on every device how can i make it to be the same size on every device.[image: Here is a reference screen shot from my app]

Comment: To Clarify: dp is spec'd to be approximately 1/160 inch. The problem is that it is up to each device to report its Density, which is what dp is based on. Devices  use "common" Density values (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 3.5), because if they don't there will be slight defects in icon appearance, as apps try to scale to the exact density. The ONLY answer that is (close to) correct is the one that uses `Xdpi` and `Ydpi` to accurately calculate size. And even that is NOT GUARANTEED: Some devices provide only approximate values for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this using suggestion of @deirahi above. Here is my implementation.

```
public interface IServiceDp
    {
        double GetHeightInInches(double inch); // if you want to set height in inches
        double GetHeightInDp(double dp); // If you want to set height in Dp (Density-independent Pixels)
    }
```

Implementation of Interface in Droid Project.

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using TestApp.Droid.Services;
using TestApp.Interfaces;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ServiceDp))]
namespace TestApp.Droid.Services
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class ServiceDp : IServiceDp
    {
        Context Context => Android.App.Application.Context;
        public double GetScreenHiehgtInInches()
        {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            MainActivity.windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
            double density = dm.Density * 160;
            var mWidthPixels = dm.WidthPixels;
            var mHeightPixels = dm.HeightPixels;
            MainActivity.windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
            double x = Math.Pow(mWidthPixels / dm.Xdpi, 2);
            double y = Math.Pow(mHeightPixels / dm.Ydpi, 2);
            double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);

            //DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            //MainActivity.windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
            //int width = dm.WidthPixels;
            //int height = dm.HeightPixels;
            //int dens = (int) dm.DensityDpi;
            //double wi = (double)width / (double)dens;
            //double hi = (double)height / (double)dens;
            //double x = Math.Pow(wi, 2);
            //double y = Math.Pow(hi, 2);
            //double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);
            //width in inches = (WidthPixels / Xdpi)
            //height in inches = (HeightPixels / Ydpi)
            //var width = dm.WidthPixels / dm.Xdpi;
            //var height = dm.HeightPixels / dm.Ydpi;
            return screenInches;
        }

        public double GetHeightInInches(double inch)
        {
            var screenHeight = GetScreenHiehgtInInches();
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            MainActivity.windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm); // I'm referencing window manager from mainActivity as static variable
            var pixPerInch = (dm.HeightPixels / screenHeight) / dm.Density;
            return pixPerInch * inch;
        }

        public double GetHeightInDp(double dp)
        {
            var screenHeight = GetScreenHiehgtInInches();
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            MainActivity.windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
            var pixPerInch = (dm.HeightPixels / screenHeight) / dm.Density;
            return pixPerInch / 160 * dp;
        }
    }
}
```

using in my PCL project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Pages.AbsoluteLayoutWithDisplayInfoPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="Grid1"/>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Green" x:Name="Grid2"/>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="Grid3"/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
var service = DependencyService.Get<IServiceDp>();
            Grid1.HeightRequest = service.GetHeightInDp(100);
            Grid2.HeightRequest = service.GetHeightInDp(200);
            Grid3.HeightRequest = service.GetHeightInDp(150);
```

Here is the output of above code

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Sorry, I did not show you how to calculate.But you did it!

Comment: No problem bro. I couldn't have done this without your suggestion BTW Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to be same on every device how can i make it to be the same size on every device.

I think you need to use AbsoluteLayout or fix size by device's dp scale.

160 * 1 dp = 1 inch.

You need to calculate Grid height by dp to show same size.

This sample is getting dp scale.

IServiceDp.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace test_view.Service
{
    public interface IServiceDp
    {
        double GetDpScale();
    }
}
```

.droid

```
using Android.Util;
using test_view.Service;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Size = Xamarin.Forms.Size;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(test_view.Droid.Service.ServiceDp))]
namespace test_view.Droid.Service
{
    public class ServiceDp : IServiceDp
    {
        public double GetDpScale()
        {
            double dp;
            
            dp = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

            return dp;
        }
    }
}
```

mainpage

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dp = DependencyService.Get<IServiceDp>().GetDpScale();
        //TODO: fix Grid height by dp scale .
    }
```

Comment: How to calculate? In 1 phone i'm getting `3.5` and other i'm getting `1.5`

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Xamarin uses DEVICE-INDEPENDENT units. DO NOT multiply by Density.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout):

```
An AbsoluteLayout is used to position and size children using explicit values.
```

The `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` attached property can be set using two formats, regardless of whether absolute or proportional values are used:

- x, y. With this format, the x and y values indicate the position of
  the upper-left corner of the child relative to its parent. The child
  is unconstrained and sizes itself.
- x, y, width, height. With this format, the x and y values indicate
  the position of the upper-left corner of the child relative to its
  parent, while the width and height values indicate the child's size.

For example:

```
<BoxView Color="Silver"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 10, 200, 5" />
```

BTW, if you want to get device Density, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Device Display Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#main-display-info)

Comment: I've tried absolute layout with SizePropotional there  size is still defferent.

Comment: You can't use SizePropotional because when you use SizePropotional, the width/height is depending on the screensize, so it will be different under different screensize. Use a fixed value as I showed in my answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunately it's behaving same Size is different on different devices. Here is the code i've tried.

Comment: ``` <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 420, 100"/>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Green" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 100, 420, 100"/>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 200, 420, 100"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout> ```

Comment: Could you please tell how can i calculate with Screen density?

Comment: It should be same, how do you know they are different? Are you testing in different simulator? Can you please share us some screenshots?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is no different than using HeightRequest and WidthRequest. Both use Device-Independent Pixels (approximately 1/160 inch). The REAL problem is that Android Density is only APPROXIMATE.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using Hard coded values for hight/width requests etc. Same with fonts to be honest. Xamarin Forms have nice layouts and Grid Controls that allow you to resize your contents based on how much space items without those layouts take. However, if you really need to do that, best way to do it is by pulling screen width and height and then adjusting values of that:

```
            var screenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        var screenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, but you could create a markup extension for that.

Create a list (lets say "_screenSizes") of possible screen Sizes and associate (classify) each item in the list as "Small", "Medium", "Large", "ExtraLarge" and so fourth.

Create Properties using the same name as the classifications above so that for each screen size, you can set specific values.

And by using Xamarin.Essentials, you can compare the screen sizes of the actuall device where the app is running that matches the _screenSizes list.

```
public class OnScreenSize : IMarkupExtension
    {

        private static List<ScreenInfo> _screenSizes = new List<ScreenInfo>
        {
            { new ScreenInfo(480,800, eScreenSizes.ExtraSmall)}, //Samsung Galaxy S,
            { new ScreenInfo(720,1280, eScreenSizes.Small)}, //Nesus S
            { new ScreenInfo(828,1792, eScreenSizes.Medium)}, //iphone 11
            { new ScreenInfo(1284,2778, eScreenSizes.Large)}, //Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max
            { new ScreenInfo(1440,3200, eScreenSizes.ExtraLarge)}, //Samsung Galaxy S20+    
            { new ScreenInfo(2732,2048, eScreenSizes.ExtraLarge)}, //Apple iPad Pro 12.9
        };

        private Dictionary<eScreenSizes, object> _values = new Dictionary<eScreenSizes, object>() {
            { eScreenSizes.ExtraSmall, null},
            { eScreenSizes.Small, null},
            { eScreenSizes.Medium,  null},
            { eScreenSizes.Large,  null},
            { eScreenSizes.ExtraLarge,  null},
        };



        public OnScreenSize()
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Screen-size do device.
        /// </summary>
        private static eScreenSizes? deviceScreenSize;

        /// <summary>
        /// Tamanho-padrao na tela que deve ser assumido quando não for possivel determinar o tamanho dela com base na lista <see cref="_screenSizes"/>
        /// </summary>
        public object DefaultSize { get; set; } 


        public object ExtraSmall
        {
            get
            {

                return _values[eScreenSizes.ExtraSmall];
            }
            set
            {
                _values[eScreenSizes.ExtraSmall] = value;
            }
        }

        public object Small
        {
            get
            {

                return _values[eScreenSizes.Small];
            }
            set
            {
                _values[eScreenSizes.Small] = value;
            }
        }
        public object Medium
        {
            get
            {

                return _values[eScreenSizes.Medium];
            }
            set
            {
                _values[eScreenSizes.Medium] = value;
            }
        }

        public object Large
        {
            get
            {

                return _values[eScreenSizes.Large];
            }
            set
            {
                _values[eScreenSizes.Large] = value;
            }
        }

        public object ExtraLarge
        {
            get
            {

                return _values[eScreenSizes.ExtraLarge];
            }
            set
            {
                _values[eScreenSizes.ExtraLarge] = value;
            }
        }



        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var valueProvider = serviceProvider?.GetService<IProvideValueTarget>() ?? throw new ArgumentException();

            BindableProperty bp;
            PropertyInfo pi = null;
            Type propertyType = null;

            if (valueProvider.TargetObject is Setter setter)
            {
                bp = setter.Property;
            }
            else
            {
                bp = valueProvider.TargetProperty as BindableProperty;
                pi = valueProvider.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo;
            }

            propertyType = bp?.ReturnType ?? pi?.PropertyType ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Não foi posivel determinar a propriedade para fornecer o valor.");

            var value = GetValue(serviceProvider);

            return value.ConvertTo(propertyType, bp);
        }


        private object GetValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var screenSize = GetScreenSize();
            if (screenSize != eScreenSizes.NotSet)
            {
                if (_values[screenSize] != null)
                {
                    return _values[screenSize];
                }
            }

            if (DefaultSize == null)
            {
                throw new XamlParseException("OnScreenExtension requires a DefaultSize set.");
            }
            else
            {
                return DefaultSize;
            }
        }


        private eScreenSizes GetScreenSize()
        {
            if (TryGetScreenSize(out var screenSize))
            {
                return screenSize;
            }

            return  eScreenSizes.NotSet;
        }


        private static bool TryGetScreenSize(out eScreenSizes screenSize)
        {
            if (deviceScreenSize != null)
            {
                if (deviceScreenSize.Value == eScreenSizes.NotSet)
                {
                    screenSize = deviceScreenSize.Value;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    screenSize = deviceScreenSize.Value;
                    return true;
                }
            }


            var device = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

            var deviceWidth = device.Width;
            var deviceHeight = device.Height;


            if (Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Idiom == Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
            {
                deviceWidth = Math.Max(device.Width, device.Height);
                deviceHeight = Math.Min(device.Width, device.Height);
            }


            foreach (var sizeInfo in _screenSizes)
            {
                if (deviceWidth <= sizeInfo.Width &&
                    deviceHeight <= sizeInfo.Height)
                {
                    deviceScreenSize = sizeInfo.ScreenSize;
                    screenSize = deviceScreenSize.Value;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            deviceScreenSize = eScreenSizes.NotSet;
            screenSize = deviceScreenSize.Value;
            return false;
        }

    }
```

And on your XAML you set the values for each screenSize, as the following:

```
<Grid Padding="10">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{markups:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='Auto', Medium='30', ExtraLarge='Auto'}" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{markups:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='Auto', Medium='30', ExtraLarge='Auto'}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- your Views goes here... -->
</Grid>
```

Please see [here](https://thenextloop.com/2021/01/03/adaptive-page-layouts-to-different-device-screen-sizes-for-xamarin-apps/) for extra info.