# Xamarin: How to make page elements remain in same size on all devices

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want a frame to be of same size on different device screen size in Android Xamarin.forms!! so I made an example to see the sizes using two phones, first phone with 720 x 1560 pixels and second phone with 720 x 1640 pixels. I discovered that the first phone frame look little bit smaller than the other.. Please how can I accomplish this???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf2wm.jpg

```
          <StackLayout>
              <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
              </Frame>
              <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
              </Frame>
              <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
              </Frame>
              <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
              </Frame>
              <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
              </Frame>
          </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Use WidthRequest and HeightRequest to set a fixed size. The unit is a "Device-Independent Pixel", which is officially 1/160 of an inch. However be aware that they still won't be EXACTLY the same on some devices: Android devices declare their pixel DENSITY, but they only do so approximately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunately it's behaving same Size is different on different devices.

Comment: I found similar question here, but have errors working with it.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537177/same-view-size-for-all-devices

Comment: Add to question the code you used. Then paste the text of the error message into the question. State which line of code the error occurs on.