# Xamarin setting button height with device independent pixel to fit all screen size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I edited the below code from a post in Android Xamari.Forms, but when I run it, encountered an error but can't figure out the error, goal is to make the button heightrequested look same across all devices irrespective of screen size:

**Interface**

```
public interface IServiceDp
{
    double GetHeightInInches(double inch); // if you want to set height in inches
    double GetHeightInDp(double dp); // if you want to set height in DP (Density-independent Pixesl)

}
```

**Implementing the interface**

```
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(ServiceDp))]

    namespace easySales.Droid
    {
         [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
         public class ServiceDp : IServiceDp
          {
    public ServiceDp()
    {
    }
    Context Context => Android.App.Application.Context;
    [Obsolete]


    public double GetScreenHeightInInches()
    {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        MainActivity activity = new 
        MainActivity();activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        double density = dm.Density * 160;
        var nWidthPixels = dm.WidthPixels;
        var nHeightPixels = dm.HeightPixels;
        activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        double x = Math.Pow(nWidthPixels / dm.Xdpi, 2);
        double y = Math.Pow(nHeightPixels / dm.Ydpi, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);
        return screenInches;
    }


    [Obsolete]
    public double GetHeightInInches(double inch)
    {
        var screenHeight = GetScreenHeightInInches();
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        var pixelInch = (dm.HeightPixels / screenHeight) / dm.Density;
        return pixelInch * inch;
    }

    public double GetHeightInDp(double dp)
    {
        var screenHeight = GetScreenHeightInInches();
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        var pixelInch = (dm.HeightPixels / screenHeight) / dm.Density;
        return pixelInch / 160 * dp;
    }
}
```

}

**Implementing the button height**

```
    void buttonWidthAndHeight()
    {
        var ser = DependencyService.Get<IServiceDp>();
        btnCheck.HeightRequest = ser.GetHeightInDp(100);
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images.

Comment: Noted! I will avoid that next time, please what could be the problem of my code

Comment: no, please fix your post so it complies with the site rules, otherwise it may be closed.

Comment: further, all of this info is available in Essentials, you should not need to do this work to get display info.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android  thanks but can't find help on this

Comment: @AtsenoguaSandra, can you give link to the post you are basing this on? Thanks.

Comment: "Can't find help" - I just linked you directly to the documentation.  What more do you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537177/same-view-size-for-all-devices

Comment: "encountered an error" but you have not told us what the error is, which line causes it, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am trying to say, that I can't find the line of code that has the error, you you said: Please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: I will really appreciate if there is better way to set button heightrequested using device independent pixel so that it can look the same on various devices without using my approach. Thanks

Comment: first, when I said "don't post errors as images", that doesn't mean you can't post the text of the error.  Otherwise we have absolutely no idea what problem you're having.  And there are many methods to find the source of the error - stack trace, stepping through the code in the debugger, using exception handling, adding logging.  These are all basic debugging techniques.

Comment: Second, Xamarin Essentials has (I believe) all of the device info necessary for you to perform the calculations.    Using it would simplify your code and probably eliminate the source of your current error.  If you are having trouble getting Essentials to work, then please be specific about the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @AtsenoguaSandra - Stepping back to look at the big picture. (First, you are testing on actual devices, not emulators, right? Obviously, an emulator's physical size is arbitrary - depends on the monitor etc.) Second, Xamarin Forms dimensions are in DIPs. These are APPROXIMATELY 1/160 inch. HOWEVER, it is up to each device to declare its Density - and Xamarin Forms "believes" whatever the device says. As a result, buttons will be SOMEWHAT different in size, on different Android devices. But do you really care? Why is that important to you? Say a bit more about your goal, and your reasons.

Comment: Thanks @toolmakersteve! You are right, I am not using the emulator due to the slowness! I have android xamarin page, which is the navigation menu of the app, after deploying the app, it look good on my actual device, but when I shared it to all devices, the buttons width and height increases, sometimes can only see half part of the buttons, so all I wanted is to make this buttons width and height same size irrespective of the device screen. Thanks

Comment: Which device model looks the worst? I'm warning you that you REALLY don't want to go down the road of attempting to "fix" button heights. If you do, to make it look right,you'll have to adjust ALL: buttons, font sizes, images. That is a VERY difficult task to get right. Devices have different "aspect ratios", densities, sizes. INSTEAD, learn how to make layouts that adapt well to different devices. There is no single solution. I recommend making a NEW QUESTION, where you post one page's xaml, and screenshots of a "good" device and a "bad" device. Say which device model each screenshot is from.

Comment: ... But for THIS question here, you need to add to question the **text** of the error message you got. (That you originally had as an **image** - please add **text** instead.) You also need to say **which line** gives that error message.